# jQuery Get Last Index of a JSON

Tags: jquery

I have this JSON:

```
{"1":"politico","2":"cantante","3":"show girl"}
```

And this function:

```
function loadProperties(parent_id) {
  var prop_select = $('#properties');
  var url = '/index.php?ry6vo4cIDRptkGe2Qyx8CMLrxAKWaJnyLLSToeP8cAA=DsJAU2F4Khnb4bankxAsQdogjwpD0tFFPOf43AnCoZ4&DsJAU2F4Khnb4bankxAsQdogjwpD0tFFPOf43AnCoZ4=HNlevL7EtzTP-tBN84ZzBMbFNXI-oegccfwSB3NYgFQ';
  $.post(url,
         {
           jqaz: "get_properties",
           parent_id: parent_id
         },function(options,status){

           var obj = JSON.parse(options);
           var len = obj.length;
           console.log(len);

           if(options) {

             var i = 0;
             $.each(options, function(val, text) {

               var multilevel = parent_id !== 0 ? "multilevel" : "";
               var option = $('<option data-parent="' + parent_id + '" class="prop-option ' + multilevel + '"></option>').val(val).html(text);

               if(parent_id === 0)
                 prop_select.append(option);
               else {
                 if(i === 0) {
                   $('#properties option[value="' + parent_id + '"]').after('<ul>' + option);
                 }else if(i === last){
                   $('#properties option[value="' + parent_id + '"]').after(option + '</ul>');
                 }else{
                   $('#properties option[value="' + parent_id + '"]').after(option);
                 }
               }
               i++;
             });
           }
           $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
         }, 'json');
}
```

I need to know which is the last index of the options JSON object in order to close the  element during the append.

The problem is that I can't calculate the lenght. I always get "undefined".
I tried to use JSON.parse with no luck.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not really dealing with indexes, just keys that, although actually strings, represent numbers.  You can get the max numeric value like this:

`var maxKey = Object.keys(options).map(function(key) { return +key; }).sort().pop();`

You can then of course use that to get the value you want:

`var value = options[maxKey];`

---

Edit: I think I misunderstood your question.  If you just need to know the "length" of the object, so to speak, you can use `var len = Object.keys(obj).length;`.

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) supported only IE9+

Comment: @mithunsatheesh +1 That's true, but also extremely easy to polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating it by looking for the "last" property.  Build it as a string and then append all the options in one go...

```
var html = "";

$.each(options, function(val, text) {
    var multilevel = parent_id !== 0 ? "multilevel" : "";
    var option = '<option value="' + val + '" data-parent="' + parent_id + '" class="prop-option ' + multilevel + '">' + text + '</option>';
    html += option;
});

prop_select.html(html);
```

**jsfiddle example...** http://jsfiddle.net/r7opf39y/

As well as being easier to manage this way, it will also give a considerable performance boost if you have a lot of options, as multiple appends is way slower than one large one.